# Unable to add primary key/unique key/auto-increment to this column

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment, unique-key

```
ALTER TABLE `clinic1`.`patients` 
CHANGE COLUMN `Patient_Id` `Patient_Id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '' ,
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `Patient_Id_UNIQUE` (`Patient_Id` ASC)  COMMENT '';
```

> ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COMMENT ''' at line 3

SQL Statement:

```
ALTER TABLE `clinic1`.`patients` 
CHANGE COLUMN `Patient_Id` `Patient_Id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '' ,
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `Patient_Id_UNIQUE` (`Patient_Id` ASC)  COMMENT ''
```

Unable to add primary key/unique key/auto-increment to this column

Have tried each one of them separately

Not working

Comment: ***check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax*** - well, have you??

Answer (score 0):

First Drop the primary key on the existing column

```
ALTER TABLE clinic1 MODIFY Patient_Id int(10), drop primary key;
```

Then modify an existing column or new column to make it a primary key

```
ALTER TABLE test MODIFY Patient_Id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT comment '', 
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `Patient_Id_UNIQUE` (`Patient_Id` ASC)  COMMENT '';
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be only 1 auto increment column in your table and it should be primary key.
Make sure that your table has no other primary key or auto increment key, if it does remove it and then try again.

Comment: Thanks but that was the case. I just had One primary key and only one auto increment. I think the problem was with the comments. They were automatically generated in workbench. I re wrote the query without them and it worked.  

But still the auto- increment is not working as it should
It starts from wherever it feels like
N doesnt notice the last entered value

Comment: Is auto increment generating a random value or is it starting from certain point?

Comment: This is because the auto increment also doesn't reset it's index after you have deleted the values from table. For eg if you delete values 1 and 2 and now your table is empty, the next value that you insert will have value 3 and not1.

Comment: The only way that I know of is dropping the table and recreating it, this way the auto increment would start taking the values from 1 and then keep progressing.
But still if you delete some records from the starting the same problem would occur again.